# Acessing a shared network folder from function app, using username and password : acess denied error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, filestream, impersonation

I am trying to access a remote protected folder **from a function app hosted on azure** :

```
try
{
    var impersonationContext = new WrappedImpersonationContext("domain", "username", "password");
    impersonationContext.Enter();
    FileStream networkStream = new FileStream(@"\\directory\subdirectory\myfile.pdf", FileMode.Create);
                 
    networkStream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);

    networkStream.Close();
    impersonationContext.Leave();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("failed to create pdf "+e.Message);
}
```

The issue is that the remote folder is protected by a user name and a password. It is a shared network directory.

To make the file creation works, the user need to open the shared directory manually, enter its credentials and start the file creation app.

What I want is to make sure that the code embed the credentials.

Here is the code i use to create an ImpersonationContext

```
public sealed class WrappedImpersonationContext
{
    public enum LogonType : int
    {
        Interactive = 2,
        Network = 3,
        Batch = 4,
        Service = 5,
        Unlock = 7,
        NetworkClearText = 8,
        NewCredentials = 9
    }

    public enum LogonProvider : int
    {
        Default = 0,  // LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
        WinNT35 = 1,
        WinNT40 = 2,  // Use the NTLM logon provider.
        WinNT50 = 3   // Use the negotiate logon provider.
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "LogonUserW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword, LogonType dwLogonType, LogonProvider dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    private string _domain, _password, _username;
    private IntPtr _token;
    private WindowsImpersonationContext _context;

    private bool IsInContext
    {
        get { return _context != null; }
    }

    public WrappedImpersonationContext(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        _domain = String.IsNullOrEmpty(domain) ? "." : domain;
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }

    // Changes the Windows identity of this thread. Make sure to always call Leave() at the end.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Enter()
    {
        if (IsInContext)
            return;

        _token = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool logonSuccessfull = LogonUser(_username, _domain, _password, LogonType.NewCredentials, LogonProvider.WinNT50, ref _token);
        if (!logonSuccessfull)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(_token);
        _context = identity.Impersonate();
        
        Debug.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    }

    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Leave()
    {
        if (!IsInContext)
            return;

        _context.Undo();

        if (_token != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(_token);
        }
        _context = null;
    }
}
```

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\directory\subdirectory\myfile.pdf' is denied.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I think you might want `LogonType.Network`

Comment: @Charlieface i just tested with that credentials, but i get the following error : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect at Integration.GlobeTrak.PdfBuilder.WrappedImpersonationContext.Enter() in File.cs:line 70 However the credentials are corrects.

Comment: Are you sure the domain is correct? If it's an AD domain, do both the client and server have line of sight of the domain controller?

Comment: @Charlieface The credentials are correct, and it is an AD account having the read/write rights on the shared  directory.